# Reducing firebase latency by only sending changed value?

Tags: c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, arduino-c++

I am using an Wemos D1 Mini (Arduino) to send sensor data to Firebase. It is one value I'm sending. I found that this makes the program slow down, so the sensor isn't able to get the data as fast, as data is being sent (which is kind of obvious).

Anyhow, I want to send the value to Firebase *only* when this value changed its property. It is an `int` value, but I'm not sure how to go around this. Should I use a listener? This is a portion of my code:

```
int n = 0; // will be used to store the count
Firebase.setInt("Reps/Value", n); // sends value to fb
delay(100); // Wait 1 second and scan again
```

I was hoping that the sensor could scan every second, which it does. *But* at this *rate* (pun intended) the value is being pushed every second to FB. This slows down the scanning to every 3 seconds. How can I only use the `firebaseSetInt` method when `n` changes its value?

Comment: How did you manage to achieve such a slow data rate?  Just to be clear, you can only transfer one integer to the DB every three seconds?  Please tell me that I misunderstand...

Comment: Apolgies if it was unclear..I do 2 things simultaneously. 1 is reading sensor data and 1 is sending the data. Whithout sending the sensor data to FB the delay of (100)  which is 100ms is accurate. When adding the line to send the data to firebase this obviously cant keep up. so instead of going to somehting like 1 second it goes to 3. Which is fine i just need to send it when value changes anyway to reduce load. Hope this cleared things up.

Comment: Yeah.....where is the database hosted, over a satellite link or something?

Comment: It's really hard to follow what the actual problem is: First you claim "the program" "slows done", then the sensor doesn't get the data as fast as the data is being sent (by the program? That doesn't make sense). Additionally, please try to be more consistent in writing and indent your code more appropriately.

Comment: All I want to know is how to create an event listener :(

Comment: @HitE I can't help you there, as although I know C, I don't know either FB nor Arduinos weird language or the sensors. But I can help you to more likely get a useful answer: With a proper question. I've edited the question to be better readable and included more useful tags. If your question is only how to create a event listener, than *this* should be the questions "heading" and more emphasized. Note also, that I don't get notifications for your comments in case you intended to reply to me, you need to tag me.

Comment: I highly recommend editing your question to better highlight your actual problem and address the problems I've stated in the prior comment: How does "it" make the program "slow" -- what even do you mean with "slow down the program"? When the program is "slow" how can it send so much data, that firebase can't keep up, is it Firebase that's too slow? Is it your program? How is suddenly the sensor not able to get the data? Shouldn't the sensor *send* data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check after every reading every new value whether the value has been changed or not by adding just a simple conditional statement.

```
int n = 0; // will be used to store the count
int n_old; // old value saved to fb
if(n!=n_old)   {  //checks whether value is changed
   Firebase.setInt("Reps/Value", n); // sends value to fb
   n_old = n;  // updates the old value to the last updated
}

delay(100); // Wait 1 second and scan again
```

Or if you want to go for a tolerance approach, you can further do something like this:

```
int n = 0; // will be used to store the count
int n_old; // old value saved to fb
int tolerance = 3;  // tolerance upto 3%
if(abs((n-n_old)/((n+n_old)/2))*100 > tolerance)   {
   Firebase.setInt("Reps/Value", n); // sends value to fb
   n_old = n;  // updates the old value to the last updated
}

delay(100); // Wait 1 second and scan again
```

Comment: that worked beautifully, no more delays everything works great!

Comment: I do not know about Arduinos weird Frankenstein of language, but at least in C having `n_old` not initialized will lead to undefined behavior in the comparison on line 3 (also, you have a typo `n_old` vs. `n_Old`)

Comment: @larkey For the first time in the `setup()`, you can initialize `n_old` and then, `n` can be initialized in the `loop()` function then.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a professional use of remote databases, you should go for a gliding average approach. You do this by creating a circle buffer with lets say 30 sensor values and calculate an average value. As long as a value is +/- 3% within the average recorded at time0 you do not update. If the value is above or under you send to Firebase and set a new time0 average. Depending on your precision and needs you ease the stress on the systems.
Imho only life safers like current breakers or flow cutting (liquids) have to be real time, all hobby applications like measuring wind speed, heating etc are well designed with 20 - 60 sec intervals.
The event listener by the way is this approach, just do something if its out of the norm. If you have a fixed target value as a reference its much easier to check for the +/- difference. If the pricing of FB changes it will be an issue for devs - so plan ahead.